# Encrypting files using PGP in PHP, GnuPG version unexpected

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg

I am using gnupg in php to encrypt content.

In a dev environment, encrypted messages begin with:

> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- 
>   Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)

For the production environment, encrypted messages begin with:

> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
>   Version: GnuPG v1

I am at a loss as to why the files are being encrypted differently.  Both are valid encryptions, but they decrypt differently (per the recipient, the "GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)" version keeps the file name on decrypt while the other one does not, which is causing an issue on their end).

The following appear to be the same between dev and prod: gpg.conf file, php version, pear version, gpg version, CentOS - version.  For the keys, I copied over the .gpg directory from dev to prod (permissioning is the same).

How can I get the prod server to use v2.0.22 of GnuPG on the encryption?

THANK YOU!

Comment: You installed different version of gpnpd. For php perl there is no 2.0 gnupg.https://pecl.php.net/package/gnupg

Comment: Thanks for the note.  The gnupg versions are the same (I think).  command: "pecl info gnupg" shows "pecl.php.net/gnupg-1.4.0" in both environments.  command "pecl version" also shows the same result in both environments.

Answer (score 0):

Copied over /usr/lib64/php/modules/gnupg.so from the dev machine and this worked in prod as expected.  Per the SA, there was a compilation issue due to permissions.